# What is the advantages of using Cipher suites in Retrofit Api request?

Tags: android, api, security, retrofit2, okhttp

I read this https://square.github.io/okhttp/https/
But I am having few doubts in that which I couldn't find from any sites.
In Api side for security purpose using self signed api(Lets Encrypt)
I am using below code in my Android Retrofit Instance,

```
ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
    .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
    .cipherSuites(
          CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
          CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
          CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
    .build();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))
    .build();
```

Also Im using POST request.
Below are my doubts,

1. Using cipher suites how the secure protection works?
2. As I am using Post request, parameters will not be exposed. But what about the base url? So is there a chance to hack that base url? Can I hide base url as like parameters?
3. what kind of security will be provided by the above Retrofit Instance, POST method and Lets Encrypt Api?
4. Is there any other option to secure api request other than this in Android app side?
5. What I had done in my Retrofit instance is right for securing Api? How that works?
6. Anything else I am missing here for securing Api in Android app side?

Please anybody help me with these doubts.

Answer (score 2):

Don't pick your own cipher suites. OkHttp has secure defaults and your HTTPS connections will be secure by sticking to those defaults.

The default configuration is MODERN_TLS and it's what most applications should use.

If you only connect to a server that your organization maintains, and if you only support the latest JVMs or Android devices (such as in a microservices deployment) you may configure RESTRICTED_TLS instead. This is OkHttp’s TLS configuration for deployments where you have a dedicated security team and control the full software stack on both the client and the server.

In the opposite situation, if you need to support a particularly broad set of devices or JVMs and connect to servers of various out-of-date configurations, then COMPATIBLE_TLS is for you. It's includes a broad set of TLS versions and cipher suites, which increases the surface area for an vulnerability, though no vulnerabilities are well known at this time.

One other way to think about these configurations: what is my exposure to a newly-discovered vulnerability? You might remember Heartbleed, where the entire Internet needed to upgrade OpenSSL on short notice. In the event of such a vulnerability you may need to update clients and/or servers. Here’s my unscientific and unjustified sense of OkHttp’s built-in configurations:

- RESTRICTED_TLS: 2% chance you'll need to ship an urgent update due to a newly-discovered weakness in the next year
- MODERN_TLS: 5% chance you'll need to ship an urgent update due to a newly-discovered weakness in the next year
- COMPATIBLE_TLS: 10% chance you'll need to ship an urgent update due to a newly-discovered weakness in the next year

Right now everything is secure, but the more stuff you support the more surface area is susceptible to attack.